# Question about emacs org mode exporting

Tags: org-mode, org-export

when I export org file into HTML or LaTex, the source code in the block cannot fold, Is there any setting can fold the text inside the source code block?

Comment: There is not. You can try to find javascript code folding library and insert/embed it in org mode html template